# Error message when trying to install varnish on centos 5.5

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, reverse-proxy, varnish

I am trying to install Varnish on CentOS 5.5 using command `yum install varnish`, but the installation procedure can't be completed because of this warning message:

> warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID ...... 
>   Public key for libedit-20090923-3.0_1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm is not installed

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to install a RepoForge RPM without having the GPG keys installed, you can either install the keys by using this site:

http://repoforge.org/use/

Or you can tell yum to ignore keys with the `--nogpgcheck` option.  **This should only be done for packages that came from a known, trusted source!**

Comment: Thank you i used the `rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt` command to install the key and then i tried to install varnish and the installation completed successfully